# OpenERP 7 entities diagram

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I’m going to reverse engineering OpenERP database, because I have to delete various informations. Is there some diagram about how entities or models are in relation? Which is derived from which?

I haven’t found anything yet.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the models you want to modify using oerplib.

Install:

```
easy_install oerplib
```

or :

```
pip install oerplib
```

Then, from a python console on the server you are running openerp, you can export diagrams like this:

```
import oerplib

oerp = oerplib.OERP(server='localhost')

user = oerp.login(user='admin', passwd='password', database='db')

graph = oerp.inspect.relations(['res.partner'])

graph.write('res_partner.png', format='png')
```

You can find more info at :
http://pythonhosted.org//OERPLib/

Hope this helps,
Cheers